# Application crashing for Android Version <5.0, Fragment Lifecycle?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a SlidingTabsLayout with Three tabs each represented by different fragments.
It runs on devices with 5.0+, however abruptly crashes on any with a lower version when the app is launched.

The following code is the fragment for the tab that is shown when the app is launched.

```
public class EventsTabFragment extends Fragment {


private CardView cardView;
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
EventsTabFragment eventsTabFragment;
TextView eventName;
TextView eventDate;
ImageButton fab;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events_tab, container, false);


    return v;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cv);
    eventName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_name);
    eventDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_date);
    fab = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.eventRel);


    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
    Fabric.with(getActivity(), new Crashlytics());


    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.event_one);
    Palette p = Palette.generate(bitmap, 6);

    int vibrantColor = p.getVibrantColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.android_colorCardViewBG));
    relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(vibrantColor);


    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Crashlytics Crash Triggered!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            throw new RuntimeException("This is a crash");
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here's the Crashlytics report on the crash: http://crashes.to/s/afbcb763b84

Can I know what might be wrong here?

Here's the XML for the same Fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/eventRel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="#2d2d2d"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/event_one" />



            <TextView
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:id="@+id/event_name"
                android:text="Sunburn Arena - Martin Garrix"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/card_grad"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="121dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/event_venue"
            android:text="Mahalaxmi Racecourse, Mumbai"
            android:textColor="#FAFAFA"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            />



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/event_date"
            android:text="Jan 16"
            android:textColor="#FFEB3B"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/event_venue"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
            android:padding="10dp"

            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        style="@style/FloatingActionButton"
        android:src="@drawable/plus"
        android:background="@drawable/fab_background"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        />
```

It's the FAB  that's causing the issue. The ImageButton outside the CardView. But it works fine in 5.0+ 
How can I make it compatible with both?

Comment: post the layout xml file

Comment: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #93: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton

Comment: Done. Sorry about that.

Comment: I'm not sure if you guys got updated. I've added the XML file.